# An invalid PHP type was specified as an output parameter

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, web

Estoy tratando de insertar los datos de un form sql server haciendo el llamado de un procedimiento almacenado. pero me tira este error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -7 [code] => -7 [2] => An invalid PHP type was specified as an output parameter. DateTime objects, NULL values, and streams cannot be specified as output parameters. [message] => An invalid PHP type was specified as an output parameter. DateTime objects, NULL values, and streams cannot be specified as output parameters. ) )

Ya he visto varios tutos y documentación pero no he podido solucionarlo. Gracias de antemano

Les adjunto el codigo php:

```
    <?php
    
    include("BD.php");
                                            
    
    if ($_POST)
    {
        $cedula = $_POST["cedula"];
        $primer_nombre=$_POST['primer_nombre'];                                                            
        $segundo_nombre=$_POST['segundo_nombre'];  
        $primer_apellido=$_POST['primer_apellido'];  
        $segundo_apellido=$_POST['segundo_apellido'];  
        $fecha_nac=$_POST['fecha_nac'];  
        $direccion=$_POST['direccion'];  
        $celular=$_POST['celular'];  
        $monto=$_POST['monto'];  
        $ingresos=$_POST['ingresos']; 
        $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
        $tipo_ingr=$_POST['tipo_ingr'];
    }
    
    
    
    $num_sol= rand(00001, 32767);
    $est_sol= 1;
    $fecha_sol = date('Y-m-d');
    
    
    $myparams['cedula'] = $cedula;
    $myparams['primer_nombre'] = $primer_nombre;
    $myparams['segundo_nombre'] = $segundo_nombre;
    $myparams['primer_apellido'] = $primer_apellido;
    $myparams['segundo_apellido'] = $segundo_apellido;
    $myparams['fecha_nac'] = $fecha_nac;
    $myparams['direccion'] = $direccion;
    $myparams['celular'] = $celular;
    $myparams['monto'] = $monto;
    $myparams['ingresos'] = $ingresos;
    $myparams['fecha_sol'] =$fecha_sol;
    $myparams['departamento'] = $departamento;
    $myparams['tipo_ingr'] = $tipo_ingr;
    
        
    $procedure_params = array(
        array(&$myparams['cedula'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,),
        array(&$myparams['primer_nombre'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT),
        array(&$myparams['segundo_nombre'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['primer_apellido'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$myparams['segundo_apellido'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['fecha_nac'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,),
        array(&$myparams['direccion'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['departamento'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['celular'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['ingresos'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['num_sol'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['fecha_sol'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['monto'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
        array(&$myparams['est_sol'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,)
    );

        
    $sql = "exec AgregarSolicitudWeb 
    @cedula=?, 
    @primer_nombre=?, 
    @segundo_nombre=?, 
    @primer_apellido=?,
    @segundo_apellido=?, 
    @fecha_nac=?, 
    @direccion=?, 
    @departamento=?, 
    @celular=?, 
    @ingresos=?, 
    @num_sol=?, 
    @fecha_sol=?, 
    @monto=?, 
    @est_sol=?";
    
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn ,$sql, $procedure_params);
    
    if( !$stmt ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    
        if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
          while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)){
            // make sure all result sets are stepped through, since the output params may not be set until this happens
          }
          // Output params are now set,
          print_r($params);
          print_r($myparams);
        }else{
          die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    ?>
```

Procedimiento almacenado sql:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AgregarSolicitudWeb]
    @Cedula Varchar(16),
    @Primer_Nom char(20),
    @Segundo_Nom char(20),
    @Apell_Pat char(20),
    @Apell_Mat char(20),
    @Fecha_nac date,
    @Dir_res Varchar(250),
    @Dep_res Varchar(20),
    @Num_cel Varchar(8),
    @Ingresos Float,
    @Num_solicitud varchar(5),
    @Fecha_sol date,
    @Monto_sol float,
    @est_sol bit
AS
BEGIN
    Insert into Persona
    (Cedula,Primer_Nom,Segundo_Nom,Apell_Pat,Apell_Mat,Fecha_nac,Dir_res,Dep_res,Num_cel,Ingresos)
    Values
    (@Cedula, @Primer_Nom, @Segundo_Nom, @Apell_Pat, @Apell_Mat, @Fecha_Nac, @Dir_res, @Dep_res, @Num_cel, @Ingresos)

    

    Insert into Solicitud
    (num_sol,fecha_sol,monto_sol)
    Values
    (@Num_solicitud, @Fecha_sol, @Monto_sol)

    insert into Persona_solicitud
    (Cedula, num_Sol, Est_Sol)
    values
    (@cedula, @Num_solicitud, @est_sol)

    select * from Persona
    select * from Solicitud
    select * from Persona_solicitud
ENDALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AgregarSolicitudWeb]
    @Cedula Varchar(16),
    @Primer_Nom char(20),
    @Segundo_Nom char(20),
    @Apell_Pat char(20),
    @Apell_Mat char(20),
    @Fecha_nac date,
    @Dir_res Varchar(250),
    @Dep_res Varchar(20),
    @Num_cel Varchar(8),
    @Ingresos Float,
    @Num_solicitud varchar(5),
    @Fecha_sol date,
    @Monto_sol float,
    @est_sol bit
AS
BEGIN
    Insert into Persona
    (Cedula,Primer_Nom,Segundo_Nom,Apell_Pat,Apell_Mat,Fecha_nac,Dir_res,Dep_res,Num_cel,Ingresos)
    Values
    (@Cedula, @Primer_Nom, @Segundo_Nom, @Apell_Pat, @Apell_Mat, @Fecha_Nac, @Dir_res, @Dep_res, @Num_cel, @Ingresos)

    

    Insert into Solicitud
    (num_sol,fecha_sol,monto_sol)
    Values
    (@Num_solicitud, @Fecha_sol, @Monto_sol)

    insert into Persona_solicitud
    (Cedula, num_Sol, Est_Sol)
    values
    (@cedula, @Num_solicitud, @est_sol)

    select * from Persona
    select * from Solicitud
    select * from Persona_solicitud
END
```

---

Los select solo eran para ver si estaba bueno el procedimiento pero se me olvido quitarlos, y en lo de $params trate de definirlo pero el error sigue igual

```
  $procedure_params = array(
  array(&$myparams['cedula'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,),
  array(&$myparams['primer_nombre'], 
  SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT),
  array(&$myparams['segundo_nombre'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['primer_apellido'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  array(&$myparams['segundo_apellido'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['fecha_nac'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,),
  array(&$myparams['direccion'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['departamento'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['celular'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['ingresos'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['num_sol'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['fecha_sol'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['monto'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$myparams['est_sol'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,)
);
```

Comment: No entiendo el propósito de los SELECT al fin del procedimiento almacenado.  Tampoco, (no es el problema, pero) no veo donde define $params

Comment: Los select solo eran para ver si estaba bueno el procedimiento pero se me olvido quitarlos, y en lo de $params trate de definirlo